# How to detect and remove dead TCP connections in twisted?

Tags: twisted

I am running a Iot socket server with twisted. Laterly I find if the device is hardware reset, the TCP connection is still kept in server side. I guess the TCP connection has no time to get disconnect since the microcontroller has been reset.

Since I only allow one device one connection, if the TCP connection goes to dead, and server has not got the disconnect request, and new connection request will be rejected.

Yes, I do define a timeout timer in twisted. But we think the timeout timer is too long, about 5 min. After waiting for 5 min, the device can reconnect to the server.

Any ideas to handle such issue ? So far I add a user command via web api, to trigger disconnect command to socket server and allow new connection.

But any idea better ? Ping back ?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911453/close-inactive-connections-in-twisted?rq=1 and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49459330/twisted-detection-of-lost-connection-takes-more-than-30-minutes?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to implement heartbeat, at specific interval client have to send some data/event to the server(heartbeat).

The server can track those heartbeat events and set timeout, if there no heartbeat from client for some time, you can consider that client connection is dead now and can disconnect client using lossConnection method of transport object. you can find transport object in all protocol classes.

```
transport.loseConnection()
```

I am using this mechanism in real time game server.

Comment: Actually I have already done this, by a PING packet request from client, aka heartbeat. It also means there is a delay between TCP got dead and server awaring it. My client hate this delay, and he wants to connect it instantly. Although I have told him that is possibly unreasonable.